# How to make logo on top left corner above the header and fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have fixed bootstrap header, now I want logo to be placed above header on top left corner. I have this current code which is placing same line of header. But I want to place it top of header. And It should be scrollable same as header

```
<div id="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-logo">
                <img src="Images/Logo.jpg" alt="Test" height="60" width="140" />
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a ui-sref="about">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="route1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="route2">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Referrals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>



.navbar-logo
{
float:left
}
```

Comment: hmm, here in my code everything works fine - logo in navbar is scrollable same as header : http://plnkr.co/edit/ACxAWXAhSUW8t1JedLGp?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div id="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                     <div class="navbar-logo">
                <img src="http://www.spzabnica.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/logo.png" alt="Test" height="60" width="140" />
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a menu ui-sref="about">Home<img src="http://www.spzabnica.pl/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/logo.png" class="top" height="25" width=auto /></a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="route1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="route2">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Referrals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

style

```
.navbar-logo
{
float:left
}
body { 
    padding-top: 65px; 
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the logo on top of the first menu item. I mean top of Home Menu item

Comment: @sgl hmm - like something like this? :http://plnkr.co/edit/uPs1YlzOWnclnDDUOFVt?p=preview

Comment: Termena Yes That's what I need

Comment: @sgl great,thumb up